# What aspects of the design of a beamsplitter cube determine wavefront error/distortion?

Tags: optics, laser, photonics

I was recently looking into having some custom beamsplitter cubes made. I require good wavefront quality, so I wanted to ensure that this was a primary consideration of the design (see how [Thorlabs has listed](https://www.thorlabs.com/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=754) "wavefront error" in their beamsplitter cubes). But what aspects of the design of a beamsplitter cube determine wavefront error/distortion (that is, how do I minimize wavefront error/distortion)? I would like to learn this for my future design efforts.

Comment: @uhoh Yes, I meant specifications for manufacturing.

Comment: @uhoh The Thorlabs link specifies the substrate as N-BK7 and surface flatness as $\lambda/10$, and then give a wavefront error of $< \lambda/4$ for this. So should we expect a wavefront error of $< \lambda/4$ for N-BK7 substrate and surface flatness $\lambda/10$?

Comment: I've moved my comments to an answer. It's really application-specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately it's going to be *application specific*.

Specifications for manufacturing using real-world materials and processes is where the problems arise. Entrance and exit and diagonal interface surface flatnesses will probably be the dominant problem assuming the prisms used to make the cube are of high quality optical material. Specifying flatness is not a trivial task since you can have deviations at all spatial frequencies.

For example a sinusoidal $\lambda / 10$ deviation with a period of a few dozen wavelengths makes a diffraction grating which might technically preserve wavefront flatness of each diffracted beam but wreak havoc for your application.

So your flatness specification will need both an amplitude and a spatial frequency component; in fact it may be a plot of amplitude vs spatial frequency, a bit like how vibration specifications are done for optical tables.

You might have $\lambda / 10$ at 10 lines/cm but only 1 nm at 1000 lines/cm for example.

[image: Thorlabs: Figure 2: A Typical Compliance Curve of a High-Performance Thorlabs Optical Table]

> Figure 2: A Typical Compliance Curve of a High-Performance Thorlabs Optical Table

[Source](https://www.thorlabs.com/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=8275)

Comment: Hmm, so you're saying there are tradeoffs? The application is interferometry, and my understanding is that wavefront quality is the most important aspect of beam quality for interferometry, so that's what I was going for. What should I be aiming for here (in terms of such a design)? Obviously, I don't want to maximize wavefront quality to the point that other specifications lead to decreased performance; so it's really an optimization problem.

Comment: @ThePointer "quality" has no definition in optics. The reality is that you have to model your interferometer including how you'll process the data, then study the impact of various types of deviations from flatness to see how much they impact the desired measurement. It's possible to get some idea using simple models, if you add more specific information about your particular interferometer application to your question it's possible there can be a more specific answer. I'm sure there will be hundreds of hard-to-read papers about "wavefront error in interferometer design".

Comment: @ThePointer I haven't explicitly mentioned any tradeoffs, it's just that you may have to specify flatness differently at different spatial frequencies. You might have $\lambda / 10$ at 10 lines/cm and only 1 nm at 1000 lines/cm. There are also specifications for surface roughness. It's quite a big subfield, people make their careers from understanding how to specify, and measure surface flatness.

Comment: What do you mean by "spatial frequency" here? Are you talking about the beamsplitter cube, or the properties of the laser itself?

Comment: @ThePointer if you scan a probe across the glass surface you can make a plot of height $h$ versus position $x$. The plot of $h(x)$ can have low and high spatial frequency components. Think of hills and valleys of a road as low frequency and the bumps and potholes and high spatial frequency. The problem can be analyzed using Fourier optics techniques so it's convenient to talk about the surface deviations by breaking them up into different frequencies. Thus " You might have $\lambda / 10$ at 10 lines/cm and only 1 nm at 1000 lines/cm".

Comment: Oh, ok, so a property of the optical component itself. There's so much use of various "spatials" and "frequencies" in this field that it's easy for a novice such as myself to get confused, haha.

Comment: Do you have any research papers on beamsplitter cubes that mentions what you describe? I can't find anything.

Comment: @ThePointer optical interferometers and beam splitters are both pretty old topics, so there's going to be quite a lot of academic literature out there, which means it's going to be quite a task to find something that works for you and is helpful to you, and I can't do that for you. What makes searching difficult is that interferometers are often used to *measure* flatness so paper about the flatness of interferometer components are going to be challenging to find.

Comment: @ThePointer I don't think that I can't help further, I think this is something for which you'll have to start with the basics and work up, there won't be a "shortcut paper" titled "How to specify flatness of a beamsplitter in order to build an excellent interferometer".  Check published theses on interferometer construction, I'm sure there have been others who have faced this problem, and it's just the kind of thing that they'd discuss in a thesis. Also don't accept my answer any time soon, encourage more answers because someone else may have some experience with this exact problem!

Comment: Ok, thanks for taking the time to help. I guess I have a lot of study to do!

Comment: @ThePointer you can also consider adding more specifics to your question here (before other answers are posted) or asking a new, more application-specific question. I with there were an *Optics Stack Exchange* site, but alas everything from cosmology to burning bugs with a laser pointer is here along with sunlight reflecting off of air conditioners.